# How to prevent img html tag in other html tags - wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, bbcode

Sorry for my bad grammar, English is not my main language :)

I'm developing a fully ajax frontend based wordpress theme based on user comments and I wanted to add a rich text editor (Froala). And as we all know that; that brings a lot of security problems.

I don't want to use HTML Purifier library, it's too heavy.

I guess I found a good way to sanitize all of my data sent from the users but I'm stuck.

My sanitize opinion->

On submit form -> get all HTML data and convert it to bbcode like style with javascript.

```
var htmlToBBCode = function(html) {
...
    html = html.replace(/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, "[url url=$2 kelime=$4]");
    html = html.replace(/<textarea(.*?)>(.*?)<\/textarea>/gmi, "\[code]$2\[\/code]");
    html = html.replace(/<b>/gi, "[b]");
    html = html.replace(/<\/b>/gi, "[/b]");
    html = html.replace(/<img(.*?)width="(.*?)"(.*?)height="(.*?)"(.*?)src="(.*?)"(.*?)>/gi, "[img weight=$2 height=$4 src=$6]");
...
}
  let editor = new FroalaEditor('#entry_html_input', {}, function () {
  });
  var bbcode = htmlToBBCode(editor.html.get());
```

On the server side -> `sanitize_text_field() all $_POST["comment"]` (So I can protect against ppl who sent a dirty xss code via console - ajax)

```
$clean_comment  = sanitize_textarea_field(nl2br(wp_unslash($_POST["comment"])));
```

On the server side -> Use add_shortcode() function of wordpress.

```
  function img_shortcode($atts, $content)
{
    $weight = intval($atts["weight"]);
    $height = intval($atts["height"]);
    $src = esc_url($atts["src"])
    $return = '<center><img src="' . $src . '" width="'.$weight.'" height="'.$height.'" rel="nofollow"/></center>';
    return $return;
}

add_shortcode('img', 'img_shortcode');

function b_shortcode($atts, $content)
{
    $bold_text = sanitize_text_field($content);
    return '<b>'.$bold_text.'</b>';
}

add_shortcode('b', 'b_shortcode');
```

And it works perfect! Correct if I'm wrong, this is a fully secure way against XSS. I know all paramaters passed to shortcode and I know how to deal with them. If they bypasses bbcode converter there is a sanitize_text_field(); when $_POST arrived.

But this is where I'm stuck...

When editor sends a HTML like this:

```
<p>
<strong>
sdfsfsdfsfd
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/9bxPvhM/86a9d5b8bc498dc5eb3689f0b983a5a7a3f1c1bb.jpg" style="width: 300px;" class="fr-fic fr-dib">
qwrrwqqrwqwrrqw
</strong>
</p>
```

Yeah bbconverter trying to this:

```
[b]
&nbsp;sdfsfsdfsfd&nbsp;
[img]
https:/i.ibb.co/9bxPvhM/86a9d5b8bc498dc5eb3689f0b983a5a7a3f1c1bb.jpg
[/img]
&nbsp;qwrrwqqrwqwrrqw
[/b]
```

And `sanitize_text_field();` inside b_shortcode function compelety killing-removing the image...

This is only a simple example. As you can imagine this is happening with `"i","sub","sup"` tags either.

I tried solutions like this:

```
  html = html.replace(/<strong>(.*?)<img(.*?)src="(.*?)"(.*?)style="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/strong>/gi, "[bold_image_mixed text_before=$1 text_after=$7 img_url=$3 img_width=$5]");
```

And yeah this is works. But there are so many tags and combinations that can broke my image or my youtube video (iframe) with those tags.

How can I prevent that?
Whats your thought about my way to sanitize html input?

I hope somebody can help me...

Answer (score 0):

God! I just figured it out!

```
    function b_shortcode($atts, $content)
{
    $bold_text = sanitize_text_field($content);
    return '<b>'.$bold_text.'</b>';
}

add_shortcode('b', 'b_shortcode');
```

If I change this, to this ->

```
  function b_shortcode($atts, $content)
{
    $bold_text = sanitize_text_field($content);
    return '<b>'.do_shortcode($bold_text).'</b>';
}

add_shortcode('b', 'b_shortcode');
```

So if I adds do_shortcode() to $bold_text; it applies other shortcode functions to this string. If there is no other shortcode values matches; it returns plain text!

But my other question is still up...

Is this a secure way to stop XSS?